# I have the scroll behavior set to smooth in CSS but how to write it in JS?

Tags: javascript

I've set the scroll functionality to smooth using CSS

```
scroll-behavior: smooth
```

I've been told it can be done using  scrollIntoView or scrollTo, but I am a bit beginner to this. How do I turn that to pure JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[scroll-behavior CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) make the contents within an element scroll smoothly.
While [Element.scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) is used to programmatically scroll to an element.

If you want for example scroll to the **header** of the page with `scroll-behavior: smooth` you can opt-in the `behavior` option and set it to `smooth`.

```
var header = document.getElementById("header")
header.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
```